# Listar un array de objetos desde JQuery, servicio RESTful mediante @GET, Java HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, rest

Tengo un servicio RESTful  el cual almacena datos mediante un JQuery que envía un json a un método POST que inserta el objeto en la base de datos.

Tambien tengo un metodo que lee los registros desde la base, y los almacena en un arrayList de objetos, lo cual deberia poder listar en una tabla html mediante jQuery.

¿Como puedo mostrar esos datos en la tabla html?

Servicio leer:

```
@GET
@Path("leer")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public ArrayList<Fabricante> leer() {
    Respuesta r = new Respuesta();
   ArrayList<Fabricante> aux = new ArrayList<>();
    OperImpFab oper= new OperImpFab();
    aux = oper.leer();

    return aux;
}
```

Funcion consultar JQuery: (He intentado hacer esa tabla pero no me toma ningun valor)

```
function consultar() {
var direccion = "http://localhost:8084/MarcasCarros/app/operaciones/leer";
$.ajax({
    url: direccion,
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (r) {
        var lista = [];
        lista = r;

        var table = $('#myTable');
        var row, cell;
        for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            row = $('<tr />');
            table.append(row);
            for (var j = 0; j < lista[i].length; j++) {
                cell = $('<td>' + lista[i][j] + '</td>')
                row.append(cell);
            }
        }

    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error en consultar.");
    }
});
```

Probando el servicio leer mediante el cliente Restlet me trae lo siguiente:

```
[
  {
    "nombre": "Renault",
    "pais": "francia",
    "sede": "rojo"
  },
  {
    "nombre": "Chevrolet",
    "pais": "usa",
    "sede": "verde"
  },
  {
    "nombre": "lkjlk",
    "pais": "lmlk",
    "sede": "lkjm"
  }
]
```

Como puedo poner eso en una tabla?, gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Tal vez te convenga usar el plugin Datatables de jquery https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html, creo que tendrías que hacer adaptaciones mínimas

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Ya me funcionó con el plugin muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Excelente señorita, no dude en compartir su solución como respuesta, seguramente le ayudará a más de uno.

Answer (score 1):

El error lo tienes al recorrer la lista: No es una lista de listas, sino una lista de objetos. Te pongo un ejemplo de lo que podría ir como función `success` en tu llamada AJAX

```js
const resultado=[ { "nombre": "Renault", "pais": "francia", "sede": "rojo" }, { "nombre": "Chevrolet", "pais": "usa", "sede": "verde" }, { "nombre": "lkjlk", "pais": "lmlk", "sede": "lkjm" } ];

function success(r) {
    var table = $('#myTable');
    var row, cell;
    r.forEach(function (element) {
        row = $('<tr />');
        table.append(row);
        row.append(`<td>${element.nombre}</td>`);
        row.append(`<td>${element.pais}</td>`);
        row.append(`<td>${element.sede}</td>`);
    });

}


success(resultado);
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
 
}
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Crea todo un complejo de html y al terminar de iterar, le haces append

```
function consultar() {
  var direccion = "http://localhost:8084/MarcasCarros/app/operaciones/leer";
  $.ajax({
    url: direccion,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(r) {
      var i = 0,
        tr = "";
      for (i; i < r.length;) {
        tr += `<tr>
            <td>` + r.nombre + `</td>
            <td>` + r.pais + `</td>
            <td>` + r.sede + `</td>
           </tr>`;
        i++;
      }
      $('#myTable tbody').append(tr);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Error en consultar.");
    }
  });
}
```

Le quité el async:true por que es una propiedad por default.

Comment: Si estas usando templates sería más legible que escaparas las variables dentro de las cadenas con `${variable}`